# Hooks Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working in a project, using react hooks. I'm getting an error message when I am trying to use useState to handle the update from a field.

I am defining the state just like:

```
const [searchText, setSearchText]  = useState('');
```

And I am trying to define a method which is in charge of change the value of a textField:

```
const handleSearchTextChange = event => {
        console.log("debug :" + event.target.value + "  ")
        setSearchText(event.target.vale)
    }
```

The issue that I am getting is:

Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

I tried to solve this issue defining the state constant as:

```
const [searchText, setSearchText]  = useState({
   value: ''
});
```

But the issue is the same.

The code of my Component is:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Typography, Container, Grid, Card, TextField, Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import styles from './styles'

export default () => { 
    const [searchText, setSearchText]  = useState('');
    const classes = styles()
    const handleSearchTextChange = event => {
        console.log("debug :" + event.target.value + "  ")
        setSearchText(event.target.vale)
    }
    const handleCleanTextClick = event => {
        console.log("working 1")
    }
    const handleSearchTetxClick = event => {
        console.log("working 2")
    }
    return (
    <Container className={classes.container}> 
        <Card className ={classes.cardContainer}>
            <Grid container className={classes.titleGridContainer}>
                <Grid>
                    <Typography className={classes.title}>Welcome</Typography>
                </Grid>
                <Grid>
                    <label>Icon</label>
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
            <TextField
                value={searchText}
                placeholder="Buscar..."
                onChange={handleSearchTextChange}>
                className={classes.textFieldSearch}
            </TextField>
            <Grid className={classes.buttonsContainer}>
                <Button variant='contained' onClick={handleCleanTextClick}>Clean</Button>
                <Button className={classes.searchButton} variant='contained' color='primary' size='large' onClick={handleSearchTetxClick}>Search</Button>
            </Grid>
        </Card>

    </Container>)
}
```

Comment: You've got a typo - `event.target.vale` should be `event.target.value`. Since `vale` is `undefined` the component becomes uncontrolled (no value is supplied).

Comment: OMG it is the issue, thank so much!

Comment: thanks... I had (e) and event ... :D